# Filtering a CSV file with AWK

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have a CSV file with alot of datum. I would like to selectively filter it and I tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat my_file.csv | while read line
do

     awk_variables=`echo "$line" | awk -F, '( $13 == "*OUT*" ) || ( $13 == "*IN*" ) {print $1, $5, $10, $12, $13}'`
     echo "$awk_variables" >> my_file.csv

done
```

A snippet of the datum:

```
1427783525,e,gf,StackExchange,HDCU3000623,d,scan,211,47969,60,1420739235,Sensor,Module,v1.06,1,*IN*
1426661348,e,gf,StackExchange,HDCU3000623,d,scan,197,48066,3,1420703835,Sensor,Module,v1.06,2,*OUT*
1426661355,e,gf,StackExchange,HDCU3000623,d,scan,197,54949,4,1420703822,*OUT*
1426661362,e,gf,StackExchange,HDCU3000623,d,scan,197,61971,5,1420703835,Sensor,Module,v1.06,4,*OUT*
1426661369,e,gf,StackExchange,HDCU3000623,d,scan,197,68947,6,1420705615,*OUT*
1426661376,e,gf,StackExchange,HDCU3000623,d,scan,197,75948,7,1420706218,*OUT*
1426661383,e,gf,StackExchange,HDCU3000623,d,scan,197,82948,8,1420707784,*OUT*
1426661390,e,gf,StackExchange,HDCU3000623,d,scan,197,89947,9,1420707801,*OUT*
1426661397,e,gf,StackExchange,HDCU3000623,d,scan,197,96969,10,1420708035,Sensor,Module,v1.06,9,*OUT*
1426740345,e,gf,StackExchange,HDCU3000623,d,scan,198,47971,11,1420708635,Sensor,Module,v1.06,1,*OUT*
1426740352,e,gf,StackExchange,HDCU3000623,d,scan,198,54964,12,1420708646,H11HDCU3000623,*OUT*
1426740359,e,gf,StackExchange,HDCU3000623,d,scan,198,61963,13,1420708647,H11HDCU3000623,*OUT*
1426740366,e,gf,StackExchange,HDCU3000623,d,scan,198,68963,14,1420708648,H11HDCU3000623,*OUT*
1426740379,e,gf,StackExchange,HDCU3000623,d,scan,198,82948,15,1420708700,*OUT*
1426740493,e,gf,StackExchange,HDCU3000623,d,status,199,44000,Run,#199.,Scans,to,date:,0
1426740497,e,gf,StackExchange,HDCU3000623,d,scan,199,47971,16,1420708635,Sensor,Module,v1.06,1,*OUT*
1426740504,e,gf,StackExchange,HDCU3000623,d,scan,199,54963,17,1420708649,H11HDCU3000623,*OUT*
1426740700,e,gf,StackExchange,HDCU3000623,d,scan,199,250950,18,1420708871,H07W770275,*OUT*
1426740710,m,gf,TMX6BP,075,d,SVlts,288,33604,27352,27352,948
1426740721,m,gf,TMX6BP,075,d,status,288,44000,183139,-33.836465,151.051189
1426740721,e,gf,StackExchange,HDCU3000623,d,scan,199,271941,19,1420708887,H07W770275,*OUT*
1426740728,e,gf,StackExchange,HDCU3000623,d,scan,199,278941,20,1420708888,H07W770275,*OUT*
```

The problem is when I open the `my_file.csv` file the data is filterd as I want it to be - *BUT* there are a lot of empty lines. These empty lines are a consequence of that line not meeting the conditions of the awk. How can I modify the above code so that the filtered data begin being written from the first line?

So my output is:

```
1426740504 HDCU3000623 17 H11HDCU3000623 *OUT*
1426740700 HDCU3000623 18 H07W770275 *OUT*


1426740721 HDCU3000623 19 H07W770275 *OUT*







1426740728 HDCU3000623 20 H07W770275 *OUT*
```

Comment: Ouch!  `awk` can read the file; you don't need the `cat | while read line; do var=$(echo "$line" | awk ...)` stuff.  `awk ... file.csv > file.csv` is quite sufficient!

Comment: @JonathanLeffer, Oh! I'm still learning! so I'll get rid of the while loop alongside with the cat - ?

Comment: Yes; no loop; no cat; no echoes.  `awk` does it all with just a little I/O (output) redirection help from the shell.

Comment: Note that my first comment has `awk` reading _and_ writing to `file.csv`.  That doesn't work; the file names need to refer to different files.  As it stands, the input is empty before `awk` gets to read it -- not good.

Comment: @JonathanLeffer So then JuniorCompressors answer below is what you mean!?

Comment: Yes.  I wrote my comment; he wrote his answer at about the same time.  He got an up-vote from me because it's what I meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`echo` prints a new line each time you use it. It's better to use awk not line by line but like this:

```
awk -F, '($13=="*OUT*")||($13=="*IN*"){print $1,$5,$10,$12,$13}' jacon_mqtt.csv > my_file.csv
```

Comment: I don't understand why but when I `echo` out $13 I get `=*OUT*` when I should be getting just `*OUT*` where would the `=` attach itself from?

Comment: @JID This will not work since there are `*` in field `$13`. Should be `$13~/^*(IN|OUT)*$/`.  If there are always `*` in front and end, anchor may be omitted: `$13~/*(IN|OUT)*/`

Comment: @Jotne: the second star in your regexes needs to be escaped as otherwise it allows zero or more of the parenthesized term.  The other star doesn't need the backslash as there's nothing for it to repeat.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ups, did miss that.  Thank you.  `$13~/^*(IN|OUT)\*$/`